# Class Stack Memory Problems (Killed error)

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, stack, postfix-notation

I made a Post-Fix(RPN) calculator using the stack class. With some help, I managed to get rid of the compiler errors but now I'm clueless on memory stuff. When executing the program, a killed error message happens in the middle of input. I can't also get out of the input. I've checked the big 3 and I think they are fine.

Main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include "stack.h"
#include "abstractstack.h"
#include "robotcalc.h"
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string userInput;
    Stack<int> operandStack;


    do
    {
        int number;

        cin >> userInput;

        if (istringstream(userInput) >> number)
        {
            operandStack.push(number);
        }
        else if (isOperator)
        {
            performOperation(userInput, operandStack);
        }
    } while (userInput != "@");

}
```

Main Program Implementation:
"#" operator prints the stack

$ operator clears the stack

@ signifies the end of the input

```
 #include<string>
 #include<cstdlib>
 #include<iostream>
 #include"robotcalc.h"
 #include "stack.h"

using namespace std;

bool isOperator(const string input)
{
    const int NUM_OPERATORS = 10;

    string operatorArray[] = { "+", "-", "*", "/", "%", "!", "SUM", "R", "#", "R" };

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OPERATORS; i++)
    {
        if (input == operatorArray[i])
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}

void performOperation(const string& input, Stack<int> operandStack)
{
    int result;
    int leftOperand, rightOperand;


    if (input == "!")
    {
        result = operandStack.top() * -1;
        operandStack.pop();
        operandStack.push(result);

    }

    if (input == "+")
    {
        rightOperand = operandStack.top();
        operandStack.pop();
        leftOperand = operandStack.top();
        operandStack.pop();
        result = leftOperand + rightOperand;
        operandStack.push(result);
    }

    if (input == "-")
    {
        rightOperand = operandStack.top();
        operandStack.pop();
        leftOperand = operandStack.top();
        operandStack.pop();
        result = leftOperand - rightOperand;
        operandStack.push(result);
    }

    if (input == "*")
    {
        rightOperand = operandStack.top();
        operandStack.pop();
        leftOperand = operandStack.top();
        operandStack.pop();
        result = leftOperand * rightOperand;
        operandStack.push(result);
    }

     if (input == "/")
     {
        rightOperand = operandStack.top();
        operandStack.pop();
        leftOperand = operandStack.top();
        operandStack.pop();
        result = leftOperand / rightOperand;
        operandStack.push(result);
    }

     if (input == "%")
    {
        rightOperand = operandStack.top();
        operandStack.pop();
        leftOperand = operandStack.top();
        operandStack.pop();
        result = leftOperand - rightOperand;
        operandStack.push(result);
    }

    if (input == "#")
    {
        cout << "[";
        while (operandStack.getTop() != NULL)
        {
           cout << operandStack.top() << ",";
           operandStack.pop();
        }
        cout << "]" << endl;
    }

    if (input == "SUM")
    {
        while (operandStack.getTop() != NULL)
        {
            result += operandStack.top();
            operandStack.pop();
        }
        operandStack.push(result);
    }

    if (input == "R")
    {
        operandStack.reverse();
    }

}
```

Stack class implementation:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template class Stack<int>;

template<class T>
const Stack<T>& Stack<T>::operator = (const Stack<T>& rhs)
{
    if (this != &rhs)
    {
        if (Top != NULL)
        {
            clear();
        }
        Top = NULL;
        Node<T>* rhsPtr = rhs.Top;
        Node<T>* copyPtr = Top = new Node<T>;
        copyPtr->Data = rhsPtr->Data;
        while (rhsPtr->next != NULL)
        {
            rhsPtr = rhsPtr->next;
            copyPtr->next = new Node<T>;
            copyPtr = copyPtr->next;
            copyPtr->Data = rhsPtr->Data;
        }
        copyPtr->next = NULL;
    }
    return(*this);
}

template<class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(const Stack<T>& rhs)
{
    Top = NULL;
    *this = rhs;
}

template<class T>
bool Stack<T>::isEmpty() const
{
     return(Top == NULL);
}

template<class T>
const T& Stack<T>::top() const throw(Oops)
{
    if (Top != NULL)
        return(Top->Data);
    else
        throw Oops("Stack is Empty!");

}

template<class T>
void Stack<T>::push(const T& x)
{
    Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>;
    newNode->Data = x;

    if (isEmpty())
     {
      Top = newNode;
      return;
    }

    newNode->next = Top;
    Top->next = newNode;

 }

 template<class T>
 void Stack<T>::pop()
 {
    Node<T>* temp;
    if (Top != NULL)
    {
        temp = Top;
        Top = Top->next;
        delete temp;
    }
 }

template<class T>
void Stack<T>::clear()
 {
    Node<T>* temp;
    temp = Top;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        Top = Top->next;
        delete temp;
        temp = Top;
    }
}

template<class T>
void Stack<T>::reverse()
{
    Node<T>* current;
    Node<T>* previous;
    Node<T>* next;

    previous = NULL;
    current = Top;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        next = current->next;
        current->next = previous;
        previous = current;
        current = next;
    }

    Top = previous;
}
```

Stack Class Header:

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include "abstractstack.h"
using namespace std;



template<typename T>
struct Node
{
    T Data;
    Node<T>* next;
};


template<typename T> 
class Stack : public AbstractStack<T>
{
private:
    Node<T>* Top;

public:

    //Purpose: Destructor
    //Postconditions: The stack is now empty
    ~Stack() {}

    //Purpose: Default Constructor
    //Postconditions: Top is initialized to 'NULL'
    Stack(): Top(NULL) {}


    //Copy Constructor
    Stack(const Stack<T>& rhs);

    //Overloaded = Operator
    //Postconditions: *this is now equal to rhs
    const Stack<T>& operator = (const Stack<T>& rhs);


    //Purpose: Check if a stack is empty
    //Returns: 'true' if the stakc is empty, 'false' otherwise
    bool isEmpty() const;

    //Purpose: Looks at the top of the stack
    //Returns: a const reference to the element currently on top of the stack
    //Exception: if the stack is empty, THROW a 'Oops' object with an error message!!!"
    const T& top() const throw(Oops);

    //Purpose: push an element into the stack
    //Parameters: x is the value to push into the stack
    //Postconditions: x is now the element at the top of the stack
    void push(const T& x);

    //Purpose: pop the stack
    //Postconditions: the element formerly at the top of the stack has been removed
    //Popping an empty stack results in an empty stack
    void pop();

    //Purpose: clears the stack
    //Postconditions: the stack is now empty
    void clear();

    //Reverses the stack
    //Postconditions: stack is now in reverse order
    void reverse();


    //Getter Function for Top member variable
    Node<T>* getTop() const { return(Top); }
};

#include "stack.hpp"
#endif
```

Stack class is a derived class from a pure virtual call "AbstractStack" which I did not bother to post.

Sample Input

> 1 2 3 # $
>
> 4 3 * ! #
>
> 20 3 / # $ #
>
> 62 # $
>
> 2 3 8 * + #
>
> 4 48 4 2 + / #
>
> SUM # $
>
> 1 2 3 4 5 #
>
> R #
>
> @

sample output

> [ 3, 2, 1 ]
>
> [ -12 ]
>
> [ 6, -12 ]
>
> [ ]
>
> [ 62 ]
>
> [ 26 ]
>
> [ 8, 4, 26 ]
>
> [ 38 ]
>
> [ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ]
>
> [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

Any thoughts or help would be appreciated.

Comment: In order to demonstrate the problem, the input is surely not necessary. Similarly, the fact that the stack is a template and that it is derived from another baseclass. Further, this should all fit into one file. So, your task is now to reduce all this to a minimal but complete example. Chances are you will find the error on the way yourself.

Answer (score 0):

## homework

What is supposed to catch the exception? I suspect a thrown exception that is not caught is what you experience.
Try adding a try/catch to handle it. Also, did you try running with a debugger?
One other thing I noticed while browsing your code is that you have a copypaste bug in the implementation of operator %.
Good luck